# Insufficient space message when downloading applications

Tags: applications, insufficient-memory, huawei

I am using a Huawei y210d, and when I try to install any app, after downloading I get an insufficient space warning. Can anyone tell me how I can solve this problem?

Comment: AnotherUser just added the `insufficient-memory` tag to your question. I'd suggest following up to [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info), which contains first-aid, a lot of hints, and links to resources on this topic. Having checked that, please answer your question if you were able to solve the issue, or [edit] it and elaborate on what you've tried and where you're stuck. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

um....free up space? "insufficient space" means that the memory on your device is running out; to download an app (which actually does take up memory!) you need to uninstall some other apps, or delete some pictures/video from the memory.

Alternatively, you might want to look into getting an SD card for external memory, and either put apps, videos, or both on the card, which would help prevent this from being an issue in the future.

Comment: No solution from those methods buddy

Comment: Maybe try describing your problem some more? You can [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/76985/edit) more info into your question.

Comment: @isuruprasad I edited your question for clarity, but maybe try looking under the [tag:insufficient-memory] tag for more questions similar to yours